# node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.9' not found (required by node)

Tags: node.js, glibc

I'm trying to run a software etherpad. When I run the ./run.sh it is giving me error

```
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.9' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.6' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.9' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.6' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by node)
Ensure that all dependencies are up to date...  If this is the first time you have run Etherpad please be patient.
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.9' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.6' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by node)
```

I have installed Python 2.7

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

> What am I missing here.

The program you are trying to run was built on a system with GLIBC 2.9 (or above).

You are trying to run that program on a system that has GLIBC 2.5 (or older). That will not work: UNIX systems support backward compatibility (old executables continue to run on newer systems), but not the inverse: binaries built on new systems do not (generally) run on older ones.

> I have installed Python 2.7

Python has *nothing* to do with your problem.

Comment: I've encountered the same problem when configuring Node.js on Jenkins CI because the OS which Jenkins is running on is quite old (CentOS 5.3) but the Node.js plugin in Jenkins tries to download the precompiled Node.js binaries which seem to have been built with a newer glibc libraries. So, the solution to this problem is to compile Node.js manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try either installing an older version of [node] or compiling it for yourself.

You confusion about python27 is understandable because many ./configure scripts are python.